# PHP DOM Scraping Returning Empty Element, "<>"

Tags: php, html, dom

I've got index.php in a folder along with articles (as php files) so that when users hit my /finance URL it will show all my finance articles.  It works but is returning an empty element, <>, for each article(.php file) in the folder.  Pulling my hair out.  Below is what index.php (the problem code) and a sample article file looks like.  Here's the actual URL https://www.stndip.com/finance/.
Thanks in advance for any help.

*** index.php: ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('../includes/head.php'); ?>
    <body>
        <?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>
        <div id="push"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <?php
            function innerHTML($node) {
                    $doc  = $node->ownerDocument;
                    $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
                    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child){
                        if ($child->nodeValue !== ""){
                            $frag->appendChild($child->cloneNode(TRUE));
                        }
                    }
                    return $doc->saveHTML($frag);
                    }
            $filename = glob("*.php");
            $filename = array_diff($filename, array('index.php',));

            foreach ($filename as &$value) {
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                $doc->loadHTMLFile($value);
                $article = $doc->getElementById('article');

                echo innerHTML($article);
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
    <div id="alertWindow"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*** sample article: ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('../includes/head.php'); ?>
    <body>
        <?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>
        <div id="push"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="article">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <strong>Powers that Be</strong>
                        <span class="author">By Ron Royston</span>
                        <span class="date">July 16, 2014</span>
                    </div>
                <iframe width="425" height="349" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1MA06RHA-zI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>           
                <p>Maverick market operator Hugh Hendry is delightful.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?> 
        <div id="alertWindow"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No repro: https://eval.in/195043

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does No repro mean?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/what-to-do-with-bugs-that-do-not-repro

Comment: "No repro" means "I am unable to reproduce the problem you described using the details you specified." It implies that you made an error in your testing or failed to provide relevant details that would allow us to understand the issue.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Hmmm, well you can see it render here:  https://www.stndip.com/finance/

Comment: There are 4 .php files in the linux folder, one is titled index.php which includes the php dom scraping code.  Apache.  Latest php.  I dunno...  Thanks for looking at it though.

Comment: PeeHaa, your test excludes array_diff.  Could thi be where the <>'s are coming from...?  The array_diff is there because I don't want to php include myself (the index.php itself).

Comment: Please set up a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Everything else is guesswork

Comment: I got it working.  Looks like the "innerHTML" php function that I 'borrowed' from someone was the source of the problem.  Below "innerHTML" function fixed it.

Comment: function innerHTML(DOMNode $node) { 
          $innerHTML = ''; 
          $children  = $node->childNodes;
        
          foreach($children as $child) { 
            $innerHTML .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
          }
        
          return $innerHTML;
        }

Answer (score 0):

below is the innerHTML function that got rid of the "<>".

```
        function innerHTML(DOMNode $node) { 
          $innerHTML = ''; 
          $children  = $node->childNodes;
        foreach($children as $child) { 
            $innerHTML .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }
          return $innerHTML;
        }
```